# How to return json path for changed field from compairing complex java objects

Tags: javers

I am comparing two complex java objects which contains list & other primitive types. I am struggling to get complete json path for the changed field in returned Diff Object.

Comment: Could you post what you've done so we can help you.

Comment: there is no notion of json path in javers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your notion of JSON path is like this `root_obj/nested_list_a/2/nested_obj_b`.

To obtain the paths to the property changes, one approach would be to utilise [`getFragment()`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.javers/javers-core/7.0.1/org/javers/core/metamodel/object/ValueObjectId.html#getFragment()) of `ValueObjectId`, which could be derived indirectly through the relevant `Diff` object.

1. Get the relevant `Diff` object

   `Diff diff = javers.compare(oldObject, newObject);`
2. Get the `Change` objects and its `GlobalId`, type cast them as `ValueObjectId` and call `getFragment()`, assuming the underlying type of the `GlobalId` is `ValueObjectId`.

   ```
   List<String> pathsOfChangedProperties = diff.getChanges().stream()
       .map(change -> ((ValueObjectId)(change.getAffectedGlobalId()))
                       .getFragment()) 
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

**Note:**

- If you want the target property name to be in the path as well, obtain the property name by simply type casting the `Change` object as `ValueChange` (assuming the underlying object is a `ValueChange` indeed) then calling [`getPropertyName()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.javers/javers-core/latest/org/javers/core/diff/changetype/PropertyChange.html#getPropertyName()) and finally appending it to the path:

  ```
  List<String> pathsOfChangedProperties = diff.getChanges().stream()
          .map(change -> 
               { String propertyName = ((ValueChange) change)
                                         .getPropertyName();
                return ((ValueObjectId) (change.getAffectedGlobalId()))
                         .getFragment() + "/" + propertyName; });
  ```

  Using `ValueChange` object, one could use [`getPropertyNameWithPath()`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.javers/javers-core/7.0.1/org/javers/core/diff/changetype/PropertyChange.html#getPropertyNameWithPath()) as well, however the last property name will be delimited by a `.`, instead of a `/` .
- I only tested with `Change` of type `ValueChange`; Used Javers (6.2.5).